# C# how to add an array to 2d array without it being linked?

Tags: c#, arrays

My goal is to create a 2d array or list with default values of `0`

Instead of creating the entire array an element at a time, I'm looking create an array and then copy it to multiple rows in a 2d array.

I have a row: `var row = new int[] {0,0,0,0};`

I'm looking to add this to a 2d array: `arr[i] = row`;

However, when I'm making a change to one of the rows, all of the rows change, this is because it's linked I believe. How can I copy an array to a 2d array without them being linked?

The same behavior is with a `IList<list<int>>()` too

**Problem example:**
So if I update arr[0] = {1,0,0,0}

all rows would have the same values.

Comment: Change `arr[i] = row` to `arr[i] = new int[] {0,0,0,0}`. Each row must be a new array, else they are all referencing the same array.

Comment: If you're constantly using the `row` variable to initialize new elements on the array, then you're just having all those elements reference the same object. So it makes perfect sense that updating the value on one element would update it for them all. Do you know the size of the array before creating it, or is a jagged array? Also, why initialize the values to 0?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I don't know the row size before creating the row, that's the thing

Comment: @sojim2 Then you can't create it until you DO know... Can you use `List<List<int>>` instead?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane Initializing the values to 0 because that's the output requirement for untouched values

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks! was wondering if it's possible. I did try `List<List<int>>` and the same thing happens when I add `row` to it.. they're linked objects

Comment: Yes but you should add a new List to each row, not the same one to each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon creation, .NET arrays are populated with default value for each member, so explicit zeroing an array of **int**s is redundant. As there is no example code in the question, I wrote a quick sample to illustrate the aforementioned:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int w = 4;
            int h = 5;
            var arr = new int[w][];
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = new int[h];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Initial state");
            Print(arr);

            arr[1][2] = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("After assignment");
            Print(arr);
        }

        static void Print(int[][] arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                var arr2 = arr[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < arr2.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(arr2[j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is this:

```
Initial state
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
After assignment
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

If this code is not similar to what you have, please add your version to the question.